# String Builder to CSV, how to add semicolos in right place?

Tags: java, csv, stringbuilder

I downloaded the data and read by StringBuilder and achieved this result
(The content of my StringBuilder)

```
User Manager_ID Date Humidity Temperature Pressure Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8
dt-001 N5_220 09/19/2021 20.0 20.0 1000.0 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3
dt-002 N5_220 09/25/2021 80.0 30.0 1200.0 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1
```

Is there any method, library, or someone else has a solution for specifying semicolons between data? Of course, except at the end of the line.
I will be grateful for your help :)
What I'd like to achieve:

```
User; Manager_ID; Date; Humidity; Temperature; Pressure; Q1; Q2; Q3; Q4; Q5; Q6; Q7; Q8
dt-001; N5_220; 09/19/2021; 20.0; 20.0; 1000.0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 1; 2; 3
dt-002; N5_220; 09/25/2021; 80.0; 30.0; 1200.0; 4; 5; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 1
```

Code:

```
public void download() throws IOException {
        List<FileDTO> tests = testService.getTestFileDtoList(); // from repo
        XSLXManagerTestExporter excelExporter = new XSLXManagerTestExporter(tests );
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = excelExporter.export(); // get XSSFWorkbook
        XSSFSheet selSheet = workBook.getSheet("sheet");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i <= selSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = selSheet.getRow(i).cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if (sb.length() != 0)
                    sb.append(" ");
                sb.append(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
        }
        workBook.close();
        writeBytesToFileApache(sb.toString().getBytes());
    }


 private static void writeBytesToFileApache(byte[] bytes)
            throws IOException {
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(".....\\file.csv"), bytes);

    }
```

This is my XLSX converter to StringBuilder. I'd like to heve this as .CSV

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: You can replace spaces ( or whatever whitespace between your columns ) with space+; (" ;") if you are sure that there won't be any spaces in your data. There is no space at end of line so that would work

Comment: Can you share input example also?

Comment: input example is xlsx file, columns and rowes looks the same

Comment: Instead of appending sb.append(" "); you can append sb.append("; ");

Comment: I can't because I will add ';' at the end of the line, and then it's no longer CSV

Comment: Removing `spring-boot` tag as it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)?

```java
public void download() throws IOException {
        List<FileDTO> tests = testService.getTestFileDtoList(); // from repo
        XSLXManagerTestExporter excelExporter = new XSLXManagerTestExporter(tests );
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = excelExporter.export(); // get XSSFWorkbook
        XSSFSheet selSheet = workBook.getSheet("sheet");

        List<String> csvLines = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Row row : selSheet) {
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(";");
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                sj.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
            csvLines.add(sj.toString());
        }
        workBook.close();
        writeBytesToFileApache(csvLines().stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n")).getBytes());
    }
```

You may also want to consider a [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) instead of a List (or String Joiner or any other solution which essentially builds the entire CSV in memory and flushes it in a single go). It should be much more memory efficient, allowing you to deal with (potentially very) large excel files.

Comment: The same result. Adds semicolons, but also appends to the end of the each row.

Comment: You need to recreate a new instance for each row. At the end of each row, toString it and add the resulting csv line to another collector: could be a List or even another string joiner with a newline as join character... I've added a code example to my answer which should help you understand

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
    public void download() throws IOException {
        List<FileDTO> tests = testService.getTestFileDtoList(); // from repo
        XSLXManagerTestExporter excelExporter = new XSLXManagerTestExporter(tests);
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = excelExporter.export(); // get XSSFWorkbook
        XSSFSheet selSheet = workBook.getSheet("sheet");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final String LINESEP = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        for (int i = 0; i <= selSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = selSheet.getRow(i).cellIterator();
            String sep = "";
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                sb.append(sep).sb.append(cell.getStringCellValue());
                sep = ";";
            }
            sb.append(LINESEP);
        }
        workBook.close();
        writeBytesToFileApache(sb.toString().getBytes());
    }
```

Comment: sb.append(sep).sb.append(cell.getStringCellValue());
 Unecessary second sb.append. It's generating error. Probably Typo mistake . 
Correct: sb.append(sep).append(cell.getStringCellValue()); 
Yours solution works perfect !! Many thanks !

Comment: Good but I'm not sure why you felt it necessary to mention something about an unnecessary append. It's not in the code I posted ;)

Comment: I have it all the time. Anyway, it doesn't matter;) Maybe someone has already corrected it and is waiting for approval. Thanks again!

Comment: Nope – I copied and pasted it out of my editor, which is identical to the above

Comment: This sb.append(sep).sb.append(cell.getStringCellValue()); getting Error:

Comment: This sb.append(sep).append(cell.getStringCellValue()); is correct for me ;)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I see what you're saying. Yes, the second `sb.` is a typo. Sorry :)

Comment: Greetings ! Thanks